# Assigning same action to multiple buttons in gridLayout at once in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qpushbutton

I just started using Qt Designer and I can not figure out how to assign the same action to more pushbuttons. I created a gridLayout 17x17, made up of 289 pushbuttons. I would like each pushbutton, if clicked, to change its text. Is it possible?

Comment: Which text?????

Comment: Could you explain me better?

Comment: It would be much easier to do this directly in C++ than in a Qt Designer. Just use a for loop for it.

Comment: @m7913d How do I switch from one button to another in the loop? Could you write an example of what you are referring to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @eyllanesc Each pushbutton has his text, for example "CLICK ME", and I need to assign the same action (change the text when clicked) to 289 buttons. I would like to avoid to do it one by one. Sorry if I can not explain it very well

Comment: To which text do you want to change it?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm trying to program Scarabeo (Scrabble). Each player has 8 letters (pushbuttons) available. I would like to be able to click on one of the 8 player letters, then click on a grid box (another pushbutton) and let the player's letter (previously selected) appear. So all the grid pushbuttons will have the action to change their own text with the letter chosen.

Comment: try with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to copy the text of a previously selected button to another button, to do you have to declare an attribute of the class I will call text, the selected text will be saved, I will call the previously selected button `previousBtn`, then every time you click, you must Write about that variable.

```
text = previousBtn->text();
```

We can get all the `QLayoutItem` of the `QGridLayout` through the `itemAtPosition` function, then we get the widget through the widget () function and convert it to `qobject_cast`, connect it to the `onClicked` slot, get the button that generates it with `sender()` and convert it To `QPushButton`, and place the new text.

***.h**

```
private:
    QString text;

private slots:
    void onClicked();
```

***.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    for(int i=0; i < ui->gridLayout->rowCount(); i++)
        for(int j=0; j < ui->gridLayout->columnCount(); j++){
            QLayoutItem* item = ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition(i, j);
            if(item->widget()){
                QPushButton* btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(item->widget());
                connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onClicked);
            }
        }
}

void MainWindow::onClicked()
{
    QPushButton *btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());
    btn->setText(text);
}
```

Comment: You saved me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tryed to do exactly the same thing but for an other gridLayout_2 and it give me this error: **The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. Signal name: SIGSEGV. Signal meaning: Segmentation fault.**

Comment: You could share your code through github to review it.

Comment: You could also use drive, dropbox, etc to share your code.